# Android Spinner with description-label different heights

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm using a spinner for selecting amounts to re-calculate quantities of recipe-ingredients.
I have a horizontal LinearLayout which I add a label(TextView) to to describe the spinner and then the spinner.

When I first load the activity, the label is positioned a bit higher than the spinner, when I select an item, it corrects its height.

How do I fix that?

Code of my spinner-loading method:

```
// Horizontal LinearLayout for displaying label + spinner
LinearLayout spinnerLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
spinnerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
spinnerLayout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// Textview for description
TextView lblAmount = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
lblAmount.setText("Quantity:");
lblAmount.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
lblAmount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#161618"));
spinnerLayout.addView(lblAmount);

// add spinner
ArrayList<Integer> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
    spinnerArray.add(i);
}

final Spinner spnIngredientQuantity = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
spnIngredientQuantity.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
spnIngredientQuantity.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

spinnerLayout.addView(spnIngredientQuantity);
if(firstLoad) {     
    spnIngredientQuantity.setSelection(spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition(recipe.getDefaultAmount()));
    firstLoad = false;
}

spnIngredientQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        reloadIngredients((int) spnIngredientQuantity.getSelectedItem());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Use default Quantity
    }
});
scrollLayout.addView(spinnerLayout);
```

I think it might be the fact, that I add the spinnerLayout with height set to WRAP_CONTENT, so it's smaller when the TextView comes in. later, the spinner takes more space in height, but the textView doesn't get updatet.

Could that be the problem?

edit: attached screenshot
[image: Top: prior, bottom: afterwards]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you have plz :)

Comment: @AftabHussain added Screenshot

Comment: I just tried your code on API 16 and API 23, but It shows up the way you want it to :/ I doubt the height is the problem though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually caused the problem,but I fixed it with centering the textView horizontally:

```
spinnerLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```